# Getting the value of a checked radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm encountering some challenges in jquery.

Inside my jquery code the first thing I did was that whenever the page is loaded, it should hide the content of the div and whenever a button is clicked, the content of the div should be shown.

It worked fine but what I'm encountering is that I want to get the value of the checked radio button and then alert it.

The code that I wrote for getting the value of the checked radio button worked only if those radio buttons are placed OUTSIDE the div but when they are placed inside the div, it will alert an empty value.

Here is my jquery snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#section_div").hide();

   $("#show").click(function() {
       $("#section_div").fadeIn(1000);
   });

   $("#option:checked").live('change', function() {
     var selected_option = $('input[name=option]').filter(':checked').val();
    alert(selected_option);
   });                                                                          

});

</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id='section_div'>
    <input type='radio' name='option' id='option' value='yes'/>Yes
    <input type='radio' name='option' id='option' value='no'/>No
</div>
<button id='show'> Show div </button>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? In one case, you refer to your option elements by ID (#option) and in another case you refer to them by name. Also, what version of jQuery are you using? .live() was removed in version 1.9.

Comment: Hi, please have a read of this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code presented cannot be verified as it's incomplete (missing the relevant HTML).

Comment: The HTML code has been updated. Kindly check the above post again

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But the real issue is that the above snippet works when used alone but whenever it is used alongside PHP  ( foreach loop ), it malfunctions. i.e it alerts an empty value whenever any of the radio button is checked.

Comment: Is there anything else that is affecting`#section_div` ?  Here's a fiddle with your code, as presented here, working absolutely fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/dxzuomma/

Comment: "But the real issue.. whenever alongside PHP" - funny that none of that was mentioned in the question!  Please read the MCVE link above and try your code in the question.  We can't answer about something that isn't event hinted at.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working fiddle here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/35vojto5/)

If you use :

```
 $("input[name=option]").on('change', function() {
    var selected_option = $('input[name=option]').filter(':checked').val();
    alert(selected_option);
  });
```

The choice is alerted even if the radio button is inside the div.

Comment: That won't work if you click the same radio button again.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of duplicate ids, jQuery selectors are not a fan of those. It worked for me when I used [jQuery attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#section_div").hide();

   $("#show").click(function() {
       $("#section_div").fadeIn(1000);
   });

   $("input[name='option']").on('click', function(event) {
     var selected_option = event.target;
     alert(selected_option.value)
   });     
});
```

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/NxMdOQ?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

You got same `id` for both radio elements and event attached to `id` hence it is causing problem.

You could either update html with class and add event on class or update existing event with `name` of radio. Update the `ids` of each radio with unique names for different use.

```
 $("input[name=option]").on('change', function() {
 var selected_option = $('input[name=option]').filter(':checked').val();
 alert(selected_option);
 });
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/qfttmona/

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/g3wdqjdb/1/) , I changed the `id="option"` into `id="option1"` and `id="option2"` on each input in the html, also changed the `input[name=option]` selector in the javascript.

```
<div id='section_div'>
  <input type='radio' name='option' id='option1' value='yes' />
  <label for="option1">Yes</label>
  <input type='radio' name='option' id='option2' value='no' />
  <label for="option2">No</label>
</div>
<button id='show'> Show div </button>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#section_div").hide();
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#section_div").fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $("input[name=option]").on('change', function() {
    var selected_option =
      $('input[name=option]').filter(':checked').val();
    alert(selected_option);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to attach a `click` event handler to the `radio` buttons located inside the `div` with id `#section_div`.

```
    $("#section_div input:radio").on('click', function() {
     var selected_option = $(this).val();
    alert(selected_option);
   });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/s0duxn5f/5/

Comment: Ok. Thanks you so much. I'll try figure it out with your corrections. God bless you all.

Comment: Sure. Hope that helps in your approach :)

Comment: The selected option is always the one you clicked on, so you can just use `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @Barmar: Agreed. I didn't even look at that section of the code. Thanks for the intervention. +1